# How to use chrome.tabs.get method correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to print to the console the URL from current active tab. Chrome Tab API provides **get** method to retrieve this kind of information.

**Working version**:

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => c_log(activeInfo));

async function c_log(activeInfo) {
    try {
        let tab = await chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId);
        console.log(`tabURL = ${tab.url}`);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error == 'Error: Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab).') {
            setTimeout(() => c_log(activeInfo), 50);
        }
    }
}
```

**Non-working version**

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => c_log(activeInfo));

function c_log(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
        console.log(`Tab ${tab.id} URL ${tab.url}`);
    });
}
```

But if I set a timeout in one second it also works.

```js
function c_log(activeInfo) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
            console.log(`Tab ${tab.id} URL ${tab.url}`);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Maybe someone could explain how does **get(tabId: number, callback: function): void** work

**Errors**:

```js
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab).
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at <URL>
```

Comment: This is a bug which should be fixed if you update Chrome, see https://crbug.com/1213925.